# TCP vs UDP bandwidth contention

Tags: performance, networking, tcp, udp

**Consider this scenario:**
I've 10 Mbps internet connection. One user is downloading 1GB file from internet over TCP called TCP.file and another 1GB file from internet using UDP called UDP.file.

Assume there are no issues with the server (or upstream) serving files over TCP & UDP. There is no packet inspection or anything, just plain router.

Which download will complete first? Will it be TCP.file or UDP.file? And why?

I've two arguments:
1) TCP.file will compete first. Because TCP has flow control and can gobble up entire 10 Mbps BW.

2) UDP.file will compete first. Since UDP has less overhead and no flow control, this can also send consume entire 10 Mbps BW.

Can anyone tell which is correct?

Comment: TCP will complete unless there is a cable pull. TCP will use all available bandwidth, and unconstrained UDP will use *more* than that, which means it is very likely to experience packet loss, in which case it won't complete at all.

Comment: Nice explanation! I though about the same but I heard TCP will throttle based on the available BW and the router at the edge would detect congestion due to barrage of UDP packets.